# How to work with mirth in local

Tags: mirth, mirth-connect

I am new to mirth connect, I don't know how to create channel in mirth connect and how to specify source and destination. I want to translate HL7 message into json format.

Answer (score 1):

The official user guide is available at https://www.mirth.com/.